# Wordpress plugin admin page loads in the wrong places

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, load, hook

I'm trying to mod a custom-cms module to a WordPress plugin.

The plugin consists only of an admin-part. The part the visitor sees is loaded via a regular WordPress Page with PHP code embedded. This works fine.

For the admin part, I've created a separate folder within the plugins dir, containing two PHP files. The plugin is activated, and the menu-item loads properly. However, the problem I'm having, is that the admin content of the plugin is loaded 
A) in every wordpress admin page, and 
B) all the way at the top of the page. The whole admin menu drops below the wrap class I've put around the content.

For A) I'm thinking that I should tell the plugin to load only on its own page, but I don't know how.
For B) My guess is that I should tell the plugin where to insert the content (using a hook?), but I don't know how either.
This is my first attempt at building a plugin. I've read up on numerous websites on how to write plugins, but I just can't get it right.

The two PHP files:

- The main plugin file: verkoopstatus-admin.php (I left out the plugin template information part):

[Pastebin verkoopstatus-admin.php](http://pastebin.com/LgUNiNjn)

- The content part of the plugin: verkoopstatus.php

[Pastebin verkoopstatus.php](http://pastebin.com/Tdu0XEqQ)

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
if($include_flag == 1)
{
*/
function showHome($project)
{
    $home_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mod_verkoopstatus WHERE project = '$project'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($home_info = mysql_fetch_object($home_query))
    {
        if($home_info->status == 1)
        {
            $color = '#2E2EFE';
        }
        if($home_info->status == 2)
        {
            $color = '#3E8028';
        }
        if($home_info->status == 3)
        {
            $color = '#F26A20';
        }
        if($home_info->status == 4)
        {
            $color = '#F1F121';
        }
        echo '<a target="_self" href="http://localhost/abc/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Verkoopstatus'.$home_info->project.'&nr='.$home_info->nr.'">';
        echo '<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: '.$home_info->left.'px; margin-top: '.$home_info->top.'px; height: '.$home_info->height.'px; width: '.$home_info->width.'px; background-color: '.$color.'"><p style="padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" align="center">'.$home_info->nr.'</p></div>';
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

the last bracket of a piece above should be at end of your file ( after div end .wrap )

Comment: Thank you Gembel! The admin settings now only show on the plugins admin page. But, the information is repeated endlessly instead of only once. Any idea?

Comment: Adjusted the code :
[link(]http://pastebin.com/fqEgm02W)

When I divide the code into blocks:

1: showhome function
2: if(isset part
3: table/html/css
4: closing php

Also deactivated all code in block 4 (don't know its intent)

test:
1. If code is as you see in pastebin, the problem is as originally posted.
2. Move closing bracket of block 1 to block 4: page is displayed only on plugin page, and below header, but plugin itself is displayed in a loop.
3. Mmove closing bracket of block 2 to block 4: Empty page.

I need to find a way to apply Gembel's solution, yet avoid the loop. Anyone?

Comment: have made some progress, will close this topic and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better is

```
function showHome($project)
{
    $out = '';

    $home_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mod_verkoopstatus WHERE project = '$project'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($home_info = mysql_fetch_object($home_query))
    {
        switch ( $home_info->status ) {
            case 1:
                $color = '#2E2EFE';
                break;

            case 2:
                $color = '#3E8028';
                break;

            case 3:
                $color = '#F26A20';
                break;

            case 4:
                $color = '#F1F121';
                break;
            default:
                $color = '#FFF';
                break;
        }

       $out.= '<a target="_self" href="http://localhost/abc/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Verkoopstatus'.$home_info->project.'&nr='.$home_info->nr.'">';
       $out.= '<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: '.$home_info->left.'px; margin-top: '.$home_info->top.'px; height: '.$home_info->height.'px; width: '.$home_info->width.'px; background-color: '.$color.'"><p style="padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" align="center">'.$home_info->nr.'</p></div>';
        $out.='</a>';
    }
    return $out; // & echo showHome($project);
}
```